# Spark read avro

Tags: apache-spark, avro

Trying to read an avro file.

```
val df = spark.read.avro(file)
```

Running into Avro schema cannot be converted to a Spark SQL StructType: [ "null", "string" ]

Tried to manually create a schema, but now running into the following:

```
val s = StructType(List(StructField("value", StringType, nullable = true)))

val df = spark.read
  .option("inferSchema", "false")
  .schema(s)
  .avro(file)
```

com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters$IncompatibleSchemaException: Cannot convert Avro schema to catalyst type because schema at path  is not compatible (avroType = StructType(StructField(value,StringType,true)), sqlType = STRING). 
Source Avro schema: ["null","string"].
Target Catalyst type: StructType(StructField(value,StringType,true))

Trying to override the avro schema (without the null) also does not work:

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("inferSchema", "false")
  .option("avroSchema", """["string"]""")
  .avro(file)
```

Avro schema cannot be converted to a Spark SQL StructType: [ "string" ]

Looks like spark-avro only creates a GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord] and I need a GenericDatumReader[Utf8] :(

Comment: Did you tried this `val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").avro(file)`

Comment: Yes, but to same result, spark (correctly) determines the schema is a union of ["null", "string"].

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you are providing the correct AVSC with the data type. 
["null", "String"] is placed to take care of null values in the Avro data.
You can create the schema of your Avro file by:-

```
val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("user.avsc")
```

Or if you have Java Schema file then you can get the schema by doing:-

```
val schema = Schema.getClassSchema
```

now once you have the schema it is very simple to build a data frame with it.
code snippet:-

```
val df =sparkSession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
      .option("avroSchema", schema.toString)
      .load("/home/garvit.vijay/000009_0.avro")

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: As a consumer why do I need the schema ?